# Javascript get two smallest numbers from array

Tags: javascript

I want to get two smallest numbers from array with three numbers

I can only get one smallest number from array. I can't get two numbers. Can anyone help me?

```js
var array = [2, 3, 5];

var min = Math.min(array[0], array[1], array[2]);
console.log(min)
```

Comment: You could sort the array ascending and then just .pop() the last number off of the array?

Comment: sort, then slice the sorted array ... ascending order ... `array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(0, 2)` ... descending order `array.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(-2)`

Comment: in the duplicate, the answer fails to mention the original array is mutated

Comment: was going to ... but it's so old :p

Comment: OK @mplungjan - done

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array by value and grab the two first results:

```js
var arr = [5,3,10,4,9,1];
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

Comment: sort sorts in place, so no need to add arr=arr.sort ... just arr.sort ... of course, one may not want the original array mutated